# Upload de um array de imagens com Node.js, Multer e Sharp

Tags: javascript, node.js, processamento-de-imagens, multiple-file-upload, multer

Além de upar as imagens eu faço um tratamento nelas com o Sharp, upando somente 1 imagem com `upload.single('image')` o tratamento é executado e a imagem é salva, mas quando tento um array com `upload.array('image', 10)` as imagens são salvas sem receber o tratamento.

O tratamento acontece no controller:

```
async post (req, res) {
const { title, description, locale, resume } = req.body;
const { filename : image } = req.file;
const [name] = image.split('.');
const filename = `${name}.jpg`;
await sharp(req.file.path)
  .resize(600)
  .jpeg({ quality: 80 })
  .toFile(
    path.resolve(req.file.destination, 'obras', filename)
  )

fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);

const obra = await Obra.create({
  success: true,
  title,
  description,
  resume,
  locale,
  image: filename,
});

return res.json( obra );
```

},

como fazer o mesmo tratamento em todas as imagens que eu enviar?

Answer (score 0):

o problema basicamente estava no "req.file" que só é usado para single uploads, quando se usa array pra uploads é preciso usar "req.files[indice]".
então ficou assim:

```
const arrayImages = []; //Para retorna as imagens no response
let i; //indice
for (i = 0; i<req.files.length; i++) {
  const { filename : image } = req.files[i]; //pegando o nome da imagem
  const [name] = image.split('.');
  let filename = `${name}.jpg`; //mudando pra jpg
  await sharp(req.files[i].path)
    .resize(500) // redimensionando para 500px
    .jpeg({ quality: 80 }) //qualidade para 80%
    .toFile(
      path.resolve(req.files[i].destination, 'obras', filename) //salvando
    )

    arrayImages.push(filename); // adicionando no vetor
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files[i].path); //apagando a imagem original, deixando apenas a imagem tratada salva.
}
```